# Size of Greyscale vs B&W image (.jpg)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, compression, grayscale

In MATLAB, on assigning 1 to every pixel with intensity >127 and 0 otherwise to a grayscale image of ".jpg" format, the overall size of the file is increasing.

can anyone please explain what can be the reason for this.

Both the files have the following details:

grayscale img: 93KB; B&W img: 118KB.

Format: jpg

CodingMethod: Huffman

CodingProcess: Sequential

BitDepth: 8

Comment: Learn how jpg compression works

Comment: can you explain the main differences between the compression for grayscale and B&W images?

Comment: There is no difference in compression algorithm, but the essence of any compression algorithm is that it will try to compress as much as it can.  Regarthless of specifically how, this is a think that you just can not control. Its a tiny difference though, not sure why it matters to you. Also, jpg is a bad format (because of compresion) to do any science with

Comment: This depends on how you tried to encode the binary data for compression. JPEG doesn't have a special mode for binary images. What is this Huffman thing you mention? This is where actual code would be useful: it'd be nice to know what you **actually** did, as opposed to what you describe here that you did. (I know what Huffman encoding is, I'm wondering why it's mentioned here.)

Comment: clear all;  

    img = rgb2gray(imread('Team_7.PNG'));  


    x = img>=127;  


    imwrite(x,'DFTBA_B_W.jpg');  


    info=imfinfo('DFTBA_B_W.jpg');  


    imwrite(img,'DFTBA_GS.jpg');  


    info2=imfinfo('DFTBA_GS.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reasons why it happens, just looking at your question.
I made a try

```
im = imread('greens.jpg');
im = rgb2gray(im);
im2 = im>127;

% check dimensions
imb = whos('im');
im2b = whos('im2');
fprintf('grey: %f\n b/w: %f\n', imb.bytes, im2b.bytes)
```

and the out put was 150000b for either.

Advice: check the variable dimensions in matlab workspace, instead of the file itself, if those are the same maybe the difference resides in compression algorithm when it saves the files.

Comment: its the jpg compresion what is causing it